# clingo apply a variable range

Tags: logic, answer-set-programming, clingo, gringo

I do not know much about clingo, i hope i can share the problem clearly.

Currently i've

```
cellUseCount(X,Y,C) :- C = #count{cell(X,Y)}, target(X,Y,XX,YY).
```

which returns results for each X,Y value. How can i get for X-XX and Y-YY range.

For instance: the rule generates `cellUseCount(1,5,1)` for `target(1,5,1,1)`. However, i'd like to have `cellUseCount(1,1,1), cellUseCount(1,2,1), cellUseCount(1,3,1), cellUseCount(1,4,1), cellUseCount(1,5,1)` for `target(1,5,1,1)`. How can i implement that?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try:

```
% instance
target(1,5,1,1).

% encoding
cellUseCount(X,1..Y,C) :- C = #count{cell(X,Y)}, target(X,Y,XX,YY).
```

Output:

[image]